# How should I structure Series I Savings Bond accounts and registrations for a family of 3?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, savings-bonds

I have bought the max 10k allowed for each of us, for a total of 30k.

Right now, I have a separate account for myself and my wife, with the bond registration for ourself and the other person.

My Name My SSN

POD

Her Name Her SSN

and viceversa.

I also have a linked minor account for our child, linked only to my account (not sure if there is also a way to link this to my wife's account).

Is this the correct setup? If one of us passes away, will the others have access to the money?

Comment: you can also add another $10k in a trust account...

Comment: @littleadv trust accounts, though, are a bit of an expensive hassle.  Might be worth it, though for an apparently wealthy family.

Comment: Why is it an expensive hassle? you can set up a trust with little to no cost with some guidance on Nolo and templates from your neighborhood office supply store.